# How can I link these two Haskell functions together?

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to remove a certain actor from a list of actors as there are duplicates. I have these functions that do what i want but i need them to link. The two functions that i need to link are `createWholeActorList` and `removeAllActor`.

```
type Actor = String
type Actors = [Actor]

showActors :: Film -> Actors --Outputs a list of the Actors in the film
showActors (_,a,_,_) = a

actorsInFilm :: Actor -> [Actors]
actorsInFilm actor = map showActors (filmsActorIsIn actor)

createWholeActorList :: Actor -> Actors
createWholeActorList actor = concat (actorsInFilm actor)

removeAllActor :: Actor -> Actors -> Actors
removeAllActor _ [] = []
removeAllActor actor (head:tail)
    | head == actor = removeAllActor actor tail
    | head /= actor = head : removeAllActor actor tail
```

If this way is complicated, is there a way of using list comprehension to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Lists are a notoriously bad data structure for worrying about duplicates, but it might help you to look at the source for [`Data.List.nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#nub), since it performs this operation (albeit relatively slowly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired effect is to remove duplicates from a list, it might be easier (and result in faster code) to use a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Set.html). A set is a data structure that can contain each item only once. So, to remove duplicates in a list, you can simply convert it to a set and back again to a list.

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
removeDuplicates :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates = Set.toList . Set.fromList
```

Then, `createActorList` can be defined as

```
createActorList :: Actor -> [Actor]
createActorList = removeDuplicates . createWholeActorList
```

Or, without `createWholeActorList`

```
createActorList = removeDuplicates . concat . actorsInFilm
```